# How can I apply a background-color to several elements on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few lists that are displayed as inline-blocks, creating the illusion of rows. Unlike tables, I cannot format rows straightforwardly. I want to apply a background color to each < li > in the row when one is hovered over. Is this possible through CSS and names/IDs?

Thanks.

Mike

CLARIFICATION: After reading the answers, I realized my question was unclear. I have 3 lists, side by side, so the first < li > in each list would represent the first row. The second < li > in each list would be the second row. And so on.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make a table with list elements instead.  Is there a reason you're not just using a table?

Comment: I have the same question, too. Why not just use a table element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-browser support with jQuery:

CSS:

```
li:hover { background-color: #F00 }
```

And for IE6 -- since it does not support the :hover pseudo-class on anything but <a> elements -- you serve it the following in your IE6-specific style sheets and script:

CSS:

```
li.hover { background-color: #F00 }
```

JS:

```
$("li").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

Comment: I almost gave you a -1 but then I realized what you were getting at, so let me state it explicitly for the rest of the class: IE6 only supports hover on the anchor (a) element, and not on list items (li).

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect that, for the class.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but this fairly simple solution should do the trick:

```
li:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Some browsers do not support the hover pseudo class though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a style to all child elements of a specific `<ul>`, you can use bigmattyh's approach but set the class on the `<ul>` instead of the `<li>`.

Then, add a CSS style such as this:

```
.hover li { /* some styles */ }
```

Using this approach you can apply styles to all of the child `<li>` elements, but you will only need event handlers in the parent `<ul>`, making your code run faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplifying things and reorganize your HTML so that each UL is a row instead of a column.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  ul { clear: both; }
  ul li { 
    float: left; 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid white; }
  .hover { background-color: red; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='list-container'>
    <ul class="hover">
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var alterRow = function(container, class, toggleOn) {
    $(container).children().each(function(i, node) {
      if ( toggleOn ) {
        $(node).addClass(class);
      } else {
        $(node).removeClass(class);
      }
    });
  };

  $("#list-container ul").each(function(i, node) {
    $(node).hover(
      function() { alterRow(node, "hover", true); },
      function() { alterRow(node, "hover", false); }
    );
  });
});
```

You can see and edit it here: http://jsbin.com/ewijo